# How to access error message from ValidationError?

Tags: python, django

In my test.py I have:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    validate_zipfile(test_zip_path + '.zip')
```

And this works as intended. I also want to access the error message this ValidationError raises, so I can do this:

```
self.assertEqual(#error that I extract from the code above, 'Zip file not in correct format.')
```

Comment: Can you just write your own try-except here to check what you want?

Comment: @shuttle87: this is about unittesting, for which there is a handy framework to make assertions about exceptions being raised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see that it is. Previously I was using try-except with some assertions inside those because I didn't know you could store the context like you show in your answer. I'm going to go and change a couple of unit tests in my own code now to do this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the `assertRaises()` context manager, it has an `exception` attribute for you to introspect the exception raised:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError) as exception_cm:
    validate_zipfile(test_zip_path + '.zip')

exception = exception_cm.exception
self.assertIn('Zip file not in correct format.', exception.messages)
```

You could use the Django-specific [`assertRaisesMessage()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRaisesMessage), but take into account that that test does a simple substring test (e.g. you could potentially run into a false positive where you test for a substring of a longer message). Since `ValidationError` handles a list of messages, a test against `ValidationError.messages` is going to be more robust.

Comment: Ty, simple and effective.

Comment: How do you get the `ValidationError.code` from this method?

Comment: @alias51 the `exception` attribute on the context manager is the exception instance. If you are expecting a `ValidationError` exception with a `code` attribute then that object should have the attribute: `exception_cm.exception.code`.